# React-native ListView not showing all content, bounces back at bottom (IOS)

Tags: listview, react-native

This is the code that I use to display a list of items returned from a JSON Api in a ListView.

```
render(){ var listHeight  = this.state.itemCount ? ((this.state.itemCount) * 115 ) : 0;
        var itemsHeight = 460;

        itemsListView = (<ListView bounces={true} style={{height: itemsHeight}} contentContainerStyle={{height: listHeight}}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)} automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false} initialListSize={4} />); }
```

However, the ListView component will not allow me to view the last one or two item(s). (trims more content when the device is in landscape orientation)

The renderRow method returns rows of height 115 as shown below:

```
return (
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.rowPressed(rowData)}
    style={{height: 115}}>...</TouchableHighlight>
```

What is the correct way of setting ListView style and contentContainerStyle to display all rows in both device orientations?

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** I noticed your question is about the problem when orientation is changed or it's in landscape. This answer probably won't fix that issue. But I leave it here for now, if it helps.

I had similar issue with ListView where the bottom items weren't fully displayed. I just set the height of scrollable area to **device height and subtracting the heights of header and other stuff on top**.

Like this:

```
const {
  Dimensions,
  ListView,
  StyleSheet
} = React;

const Viewport = Dimensions.get('window');

...

render() {
  return (
    <ListView ... style={styles.listView} />
  )
}

...

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
  listView: {
    height: Viewport.height
  }
});
```

Also style `flex: 1` could fix your problem, so you can try that at first.

Comment: Hi, setting flex: 1 to all parent components solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: It's not stated in the documentation explicitly, but ListViews and other ScrollViews need to have a parent with a height greater than 0. Setting 'flex: 1' is one way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

not perfectly answer to the question, but might help some.. i had set top, left, right, but Not the bottom, and that caused the scrollview to be full height, so it woulnt need to scroll.